# How to know if a user verified his mail while he was logged in with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have a login with firebase auth which I have a condition that if the user has not verified the email with which he registered, he closes the session after 5 minutes.

When the 5 minutes pass I am consulting firebase again the status of the user to check if it has already verified the mail, I do it in the following way

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

This brings me the user's information, but it tells me that the email has not been verified even when it was already done, this happens only if it has not closed session, if it is logged in again it already indicates that the email is verified if the user has did.

How do I know if the user's email has already been verified if this was done while he was logged in and has not closed session?

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) 
        {
            if(!user.emailVerified)
            {
                vm.logout()
            }
            else
            {
                vm.emailVerified = true;
                this.heightGrid();
            }
        }
    });
```

With this other method it doesn't work for me either

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged
```

This one, like the other one, returns false the verification as long as the session is not closed and reopened, but I need to know if it already did it while the session was open, to prevent the application from forcing the session out

Comment: hmm.. I'm not too familiar with this, but are you saying `firebase.auth()` raises `AuthStateChanged`? and that your registered callback is being called in that event, but not pickup up on authdata changes?  what change is occurring then?

Comment: @BrettCaswell It is not returning me the updated data of the mail verification, not while the session is still active, if it closes and reopens if it brings it correctly

Comment: well.. I think part of the confusion for me here (not having worked much with this technology) is that there is a logout occurring at all.  This consideration here really should be based on access_tokens and the mechanisms and workflows around renewing them when they expire, not sessions necessarily.

Comment: also, your response to my inquiry, and the code snippet above gives me pause.. you don't seem like you're registering callbacks or handling events, you seem like you're invoking these event delegates. am I mistaken?

Comment: This isnt possible. What we do is to not allow the user to login until they have verified their email. We pass a continue url to the verification email so after firebase confirms it they are directed back to our site.